# PHP: translate POST into simple variables?

Tags: php, forms

I know this is totally wrong, I didn't write the app, I just have to make it work while I work on the new one. Seems like GoDaddy made some updates to our account so now there are some things that don't work. I already turned register globals on and a lot of things went back to normal. Now, this doesn't work...

There is a hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="SUBMIT1" value="1" />`

There is a check for that field

```
if($SUBMIT1) {
  // this part never gets executed. 
}
```

I know I can easily fix it by doing this instead...

```
if($_POST['SUBMIT1']) {
  // this part never gets executed. 
}
```

The problem is, this is a huge app and it's going to take a loooong time to do that everywhere. Is there a way or a setting I can turn on so that when a form is submitted `$_POST['WHATEVER']` also works as `$WHATEVER`?

Comment: What you are describing is called `Register Globals` which you already indicated you turned on. So, I'd start with checking to see if what you did to turn Register Globals on really worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to get the exact functionality you described:

```
extract($_POST);
```

Please note the possible safety issue here: a user could send extra data in `$_POST` and "overwrite" the values of existing variables in your code. You can pass a second parameter to `extract` to prevent these problems:

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);
```

This will skip extracting any fields in the `$_POST` array that already have matching variables in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
$_POST =  array('SUBMIT1' => 'SUBMIT ONE', 'SUBMIT2' => 'SUBMIT  TWO');

foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    define(''. $k. '', $v);
}

echo SUBMIT1;  // and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST  as $key => $value ) {

        if(is_array($value)){
            foreach ($value as $k => $v ) {
                $$k = $v ;

            }
        }else{

            $$key=$value;
        }

        echo $key ." : " .$value."<br>";
}
```