# PHP: how to make this variable have a value

Tags: php, global

I have register globals on, I know, I know, bad idea, I didn't program the app, I just have to make it work while I work on their new app. Seems like the hosting company made some kind of update, know the app doesn't work.

```
function showfield($fldn_,$flds_,$edit_, $onch_='', $maxlen_='255',$format_='', $align_='left', $extra_='') {
  switch ($format_) {
    case 'curr':
        $fldv_=curr($GLOBALS[$fldn_]);
        break;
    case 'currn':
        $fldv_=currn($GLOBALS[$fldn_]);
        break;
    default:
        $fldv_=$GLOBALS[$fldn_];
  }
  if($edit_=='2'){ 
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$fldn_.'" id="'.$fldn_.'" VALUE="'.$fldv_.'" SIZE="'.afsize($flds_).'"';
    if ($onch_) echo " onChange=\"$onch_\"";
    if ($maxlen_) echo " maxlength=\"$maxlen_\"";
    if ($align_ and $align_<>'left') echo " style=\"text-align:$align_\"";
    echo " $extra_>";
  } else { echo $fldv_; }
}
```

Note this part of the function above... `$fldv_=$GLOBALS[$fldn_];` That doesn't work anymore, it's supposed to add a value to `VALUE="'.$fldv_.'"`. I don't know where it is supposed to get the value from. I did a search on the code and can't find a reference where the variable is set. Anyways, everything where $GLOBALS is, doesn't work anymore.  I already set register_globals to On and IT IS on.

It used to work, but after the update, doesn't work anymore.

Comment: My guess: On php.ini file, they changed register_globals=off. Ask them about the exact nature of the update.

Comment: register_globals in On, I'm sure of it. I made the change in the control panel too. after I turned register_globals on, a lot of other functions started working.

Comment: Maybe 1.) you need to restart apache to activate changes to php.ini (just making sure), or 2.) that specific element $globals[$fldn_] is not being set (and you won't find it as it appears because $fldn_ is a value you got in the funcion parameters)... print $GLOBALS and check where is showfield() called to you can infer what does $fldn_ param means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used extract on $_POST to fix some problems, I just had to do it on $_GET too: [PHP: translate POST into simple variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589345/php-translate-post-into-simple-variables)

```
extract($_GET, EXTR_SKIP);
```